If $\Vert cs\Vert$ is short in a lattice signature, how large can $s$ be?
I would like a result of the following form:
"Let $s\in \mathcal{R}_q^n$ where $\mathcal{R}_q = \mathbb{Z}_q[x]/(x^d+1)$. If $\Vert s\Vert > q$, then (with all but negligible probability) for a randomly chosen challenge polynomial $c\in\mathcal{R}_q$ such that $c$ has precisely $\tau$ non-zero coefficients, all from $\pm 1$, then $\Vert cs\Vert\geq B$ (for some bound $B$)."
I've found some bounds for the case when $C$ is a randomly chosen matrix, but they rely critically on the independence of the rows of $C$, which fails for $c\in\mathcal{R}_q$. I've tried some strategies to prove this myself, but I thought this is a problem others have probably run into.

If I'm reading your post correctly, you want a "reversed" form of a Chernoff bound (which would correspond to bounding $\lVert cs\rVert < B$ instead). These are typically a lot harder than standard Chernoff bounds, to the point that I wouldn't feel confident in this being a problem that is commonly solved in lattice crypto. I used something similar in this, but it took a lot of massaging to get a reasonable looking cryptographic statement that is amenable to the pre-existing math for proving statements of your type (and that paper is over $\mathbb{Z}$)

That being said, I think the standard way to connect this to the math literature would be to look for "small ball probabilities". See for example this. In particular, something like Lemma 6.2 implies that if you could get a strong enough upper-bound on the characteristic function of $cs$, you would be good. I would not be personally super optimistic about this, but it's possible you can randomly get some negligible upper bound on it that works for you.
